# how to pass input text value as method parameter from JSF page to Managedbean?

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee

I want to pass input text value as method parameter from jsf page to managedbean as i submit the form. like

```
<h:form>
   <p:inputText name="fname"/>
   <P:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{myClass.save(inputText value as parameters)}">
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 1):

The standard approach is the following:

```
<h:form> 
    <p:inputText value="#{myClass.inputValue}"/> 
    <p:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{myClass.doSomething}"> 
</h:form>
```

**MyClass** class:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class myClass {
    private String inputValue;

    // getter and setter for inputValue

    public void doSomething() {
    }
}
```

When the user clicks the button, before `doSomething` is invoked, `JSF` cares about reading the value inputed in the `inputText` component, validating it if necessary, and invoking setter class for `inputValue` as per the EL expression `#{myClass.inputValue}` (note that EL automagically understands that the `setter` must be invoked in this case). This is very basic JSF. I recommend to study some Java EE 6 tutorial ([this](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/), for example).

Comment: i mean if i set inputext value from different object But i want to pass the user input value as method parameters.
    <p:inputText value="#{loginHandler.currentuser.name}">
      <p:commandButton value="Update" action="myClass.update( user Input as parameters)">